# Spring boot 2 hibernate multiple schema

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, multiple-schema

I have one db (MySql) and several schemas (schema_a,schema_b,schema_c). The schemas have same tables, identical.

The current schema depends on current user (session) data. For example, current user is from company A, then current schema is "schema_a". Accordingly, EmployeeRepository.findAll() method fetches data from schema "schema_a".

In hibernate with spring boot 2, is it possible dynamically change current entityManager? If yes, how?

Help, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is referred to as a multi tenant architecture.

You could set the `catalog` (that is the schema in your case) based on some authentication information.

How you would do that is implement an `interceptor` that determines what schema needs to be set and then sets the correct "tenant" to the `TheardLocal` (on which your request is running). I have used this approach with great success and I do believe it is **exactly** what you are looking for.

I could write it out here, however there is no need to keep repeating what already exists. There is a very good article, which was the inspiration for my solution, and I suggest you take a look [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation).

Comment: @Norbest Bisci thanx for your answer. I didn't know MultiTenancy approach :)

Comment: @dosmac I know the feeling, when I had that problem I searched for a looong time. glad it helped! Happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

I realised that when I use both MySQL and PostgreSQL. The first parameter is different.

For MySQL:

**schema = "data"**

```
@Table(schema = "data", name = "datasourcesample")
```

For PostgreSQL:

**catalog = "data1"**

```
@Table(catalog = "data1", name = "datasourcesample")
```